# How can I conditionally add multiple properties to an object type based on a generic union?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, union-types, conditional-types

Given this union type:

```
type Union = "a" | "b";
```

How can I add multiple new keys to an object type? I know I can do this with a single condition:

```
type Condition<T extends Union> = {
  [K in T extends "a" ? "someProp" : never]: string;
}

type Result = Condition<"a">;

// type Result = {
//   someProp: string;
// }
```

But when I try to add another key with a condition as well I get a syntax error:

```
type Condition<T extends Union> = {
  [K in T extends "a" ? "someProp" : never]: string;
  [K in T extends "a"? "anotherProp": never]: string;
//        ~~~~~~~      ~~~~~~~~~~~~        ~
}
```

Why can't I just do two simple checks there?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigIgIaagHywCNMBuAKHNEigGEUATBYZOAHgBUoIAPYCOAwDOsRCgB86KAG9yUKAG0A0lASouvfoJE48AfixCkAWwgAFAE5IweAFxQ4EAG4QLAXXtDgFtQHMK8sqq6tx8AsJYuAY4cEjAABaultaY9o4u7p7efhQA9LnyhYUAfqVlxUXy5dVllSXkAL5AA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union in the condition in the index signature:

```
type Union = "a" | "b";

type Condition<T extends Union> = {
  [K in T extends "a" ? "someProp" | "anotherProp" : never]?: string;
}

const a: Condition<"a"> = {
  someProp: "foo",
  anotherProp: "foo",
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigIgIaagHywCNMBuAKHNEigGEUATBYZOAHgBUoIAPYCOAwDOsRCgB86KAG9yUKAG0A0lASouvfoJE48AfixCkAWwgAFAE5IweQjjhJgACwgXL1vAC4ocCADdXAF09byFgCzUAcwoAX0oAYxQwqGxvekFmVjZdSQxZeSNTdzBvTAAzJCRMABo5FIdnV2LSiqramKA)